# Rotation of velocity vectors in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

I want to rotate a $(X,Y,Z)$ coordinate-system around it $Z$-axis. For the coordinates this can be done with the rotation matrix:

$$
R_Z(\theta)= \begin{pmatrix}
cos \theta & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

($R_Z(\theta)$ because I want to rotate around the $Z$-axis). To get the final coordinates, take the dot product of this with the position vector $\vec{u}$:

$$
\vec{u_{rot}} = R_Z \cdot \vec{u} 
$$

Does this also work too for the velocity vector $\vec{v}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but only because the rotation is about the origin.

The velocity is the time derivative of the position, so if the position at time $t$ is $\vec u(t)$, then the velocity is
$$\vec v(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \vec u(t) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h ( \vec u(t+h) - \vec u(t) ) $$

If we compute this in the rotated coordinate system, we get

$$ \begin{align}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h ( R\vec u(t+h) - R\vec u(t))
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h R(\vec u(t+h) - \vec u(t))
\\&= \lim_{h\to 0} R\frac1h (\vec u(t+h) - \vec u(t))
\\&= R\lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h (\vec u(t+h) - \vec u(t))
= R \vec v(t) \end{align}$$

the first two equals signs are because $R$ is a *linear transformation*; the third is because $R$ is *continuous* and so preserves limits.

Note that this is **not true** for a rotation $T$ about a *different* point than the origin, because then $T\vec u(t+h)-T\vec u(t) \neq T(\vec u(t+h)-\vec u(t))$ in general.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. So the same $R_Z$ is used, that was something else I wasn't sure of